# Mysql query to get simple and variable product only if the parent product is published

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I want to get a list of all the simple and variable products that have been published. The problem is that if the parent product is a draft, the product variables is still displayed.
My code:

```
SELECT 
   p.ID,
   p.post_title,
   p.post_excerpt,
   p.post_parent
from
   wp_posts p 
WHERE 
   p.post_type in ('product','product_variation')
   AND p.post_status = 'publish'
   GROUP BY p.ID
```

Thanks...

**Update:**

[Simple and variable product list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAfbG.jpg)

The parent product "test variable III" is pending, but the variable products are also displayed.

Comment: Can you update your post with some sample input data, current output and expected output?

Comment: hi, post updated... @lemon